# passing data from javaclass to html webview

Tags: android

I'm using a webview in my app.

now what I want to do is to pass the data from my javaclass to html.
fro example I have a textview in my android javaclass and when I hit the button send the webview will show with html saying Hi + the name that I input in textview.

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check [Using WebViews](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2008/09/using-webviews.html) may be it will help

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your html and then load it to WebView using [loadData](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method for example.

Or you can use [addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) to invoke methods of some Java object from javaScript code in WebView

Answer (score 0):

See below code

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.loadUrl("http://www.xxx.com/web/apps/jots.do");
```

Comment: but I'm loading a url in my webview. that's why i need to pass the variable that hold the data to my html.

Comment: can please specify the properties? sorry I'm a newbie in android.  =)

Comment: like what is the b.getString is that the textview or?

Comment: What do you mean to say by this?